# Error in creating a database table using php

Tags: php, mysql

i want to create a table in the database using php (mysql_querry)

Table is having 'n' number of attributes.
out of n, n-2 attribute names are available in the array.

I can't explain where i am getting the array but it looks like this- 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH98f.png

Here is the code for generating String to execute in mysql_querry.

```
    $str="CREATE TABLE $register_name(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, date DATE, ";
    $j=0;
    while($j<$i)
    {
        $str=$str.$roll_no[$j]." int(100), ";
        $j++;

    }
    $str=$str."PRIMARY KEY(id))";


require('blogic.php');
$obj = new blogic();
$createtable=$obj->create($str);
```

When i echo the $str, I get this:

```
CREATE TABLE $register_name(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, date DATE, 913310128 int(100), 0913310129 int(100), PRIMARY KEY(id))
```

However, it is giving error like this

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '913310128 int(100), 0913310129 int(100), PRIMARY KEY(id))' at
>   line 1

I don't understand the problem. when i don't use roll_no array, it works fine..
Please let me know what is the problem in this.

Comment: I have never seen mysql field names beeing a number like 913310128, check if this is allowed. Consider to change it to something like i_ 913310128

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/identifiers.html):

"Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits."

So, you could just quote the name:

```
$str=$str."`".$roll_no[$j]."` int(100), ";
```

Or, prefix it with a letter:

```
$str=$str."c".$roll_no[$j]." int(100), ";
```

Comment: I think the quotes need to be backquotes.

Comment: You tried it with the backticks or the single quotes that Russell originally put in his answer?

Comment: If you didn't try what I wrote, why did you say it didn't work?

Comment: Giving columns numeric names is just asking for trouble. Put a letter in front, like Russell's second suggestion.